# Loading several SQL tables from a database in R

Tags: r, rodbc

I have a local mysql database with some tables in it. I can load the tables one a time like so:

```
library(DBI)
library(odbc)
library(RODBC)

myconn1 <- odbcConnect("mysqldsn")
employees <- sqlQuery(myconn1, "SELECT * FROM employees;")
customers <- sqlQuery(myconn1, "SELECT * FROM customers;")
```

I want to load all the tables from the database into a list in R. I am trying to use a for loop to do so:

```
list_tables <- list()

for (i in sqlQuery(myconn1, "SHOW TABLES;")){
  list_tables[[i]] <- sqlQuery(myconn1, paste("SELECT * FROM", i,";"))
}
```

However, I get the error:
Error in `[[<-`(`*tmp*`, i, value = sqlQuery(myconn1, paste("SELECT * FROM",  :
no such index at level 1

I know that I do not have a representative dataset but I am not sure how to upload an sql database on stackoverflow.

Comment: Where does the `mytables` object come from? Above the for loop you define a `list_tables` but you are not assigning to it.

Comment: @brendbech Edited the original post. Thank you for pointing it out!